# List comprehension with append in one line

Tags: python, list

I am trying to use list comprehension for a Numpy array and then append another element after. Then I noticed something strange.

```
a = [i for i in machine]
a.append("All")
print(a)
```

This returns [251, 360, 661, 662, 852, 'All']

While

```
a = [i for i in machine].append("All")
```

Returns None

Why does this returns a None object? Is there a way to do this in one line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`append` changes the list you call it on. It doesn’t produce a new list, so it returns `None` to avoid confusion.

Python 3.6+, using a splat (expands an iterable) in a list literal:

```
a = [*machine, "All"]
```

previously, list concatenation with the `+` operator:

```
a = list(machine) + ["All"]
```